# How to install OroCRM extension?

Tags: installation, marketplace, orocrm

I want to install https://marketplace.oroinc.com/orocrm/extension/mailchimp-integration/

How to fill the following cmd,

```
composer require <extension name>:<extension-version> –prefer-dist –update-no-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Extension name can be found in an extension page at the marketplace:
[image: mailchimp-extension-page]
As for the version, you can skip it and run the command like this:

```
composer require oro/mailchimp --prefer-dist --update-no-dev
```

As a result, the composer will automatically install the latest available version, that is compatible with your application.

Alternatively, you can check all the available versions at https://satis.oroinc.com.

Comment: I am getting following error => [InvalidArgumentException]                                                   
  Could not find a matching version of package oro/mailchimp. Check the packa  
  ge spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a  
   stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).

Comment: Please specify, what version of the oro/platform package do you use?

Comment: How to find version after installed?

Comment: Why i am getting following error when i try to see version => info: No menu item `oro/platform' in node `(dir)Top'.

Comment: what operation system do you use?

Comment: Centos 7 and nginx.

Comment: Sometimes i am facing the issue => There was an error performing the requested operation. Please try again or contact us for assistance. How to avoid this message? @Anyt , Michael Bessolov

Comment: As mentioned in an extension page and in the error message you shared, Mailchimp extension is compatible with OroPlatform 3.1, but you have OroPlatform 4.0. So the extension cannot be installed because of the compatibility issue